# Need help from an experienced with preg_replace () function

Tags: php

As you know `ereg_replace` is deprecated now.
I tried to pass to `preg_replace` but nothing works as before with `ereg_replace`.

I want to change the `ereg_replace` here:

```
$test = ereg_replace("%5C%22", "%22", $test);

$tar = ereg_replace(" ", "", $tar);

$test2 = ereg_replace("#EM#", $tar, $test2);

$su = ereg_replace("&emar&", $tar, $su);
```

I've edited with `preg_replace` like this but I don't know if it's correct

```
$test = preg_replace('/%5C%22/', '%22', $test, -1);

$tar = preg_replace(/ /, '', $tar, -1);

$test2 = preg_replace('/#EM#/', $tar, $test2, -1);

$su = preg_replace('/&emar&/', $tar, $su, -1);
```

this one :

```
$test2 = preg_replace('/#EM#/', $tar, $test2, -1);
```

is correct or I change to:

```
$test2 = preg_replace('/\#EM\#/', $tar, $test2, -1);
```

Thank you.

Comment: collect or not is easy to check by writing some small tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference in your examples would be that you need to add Delimiters.

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~).

But, that being said, in your case it will be more performant and simpler to use `str_replace` as you are not really using any regular expression pattern.